# reboot in a click mouse loop not working

Tags: loops, timer, autohotkey

I am trying to reboot PC at specific hour when a click mouse loop is running. I used if + else conditions and when I try to run both pieces of code separately the script works but when put together only the mouse clicking loop is running while the timer process takes no effect. Any ideas what’s wrong?

```
^+f::
  SetTimer, Chronos, 500
  return


Chronos:

  FormatTime, TimeToMeet,,HHmm
  If (TimeToMeet = 2018) 
  {
    Run, %comspec% /c shutdown -r -f -t 0
  } 
  else
  {
    loop
    {
      MouseClick, Left, 787, 512, 1,0
      Sleep 10000
    }
  }

  Return

k::Pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop statement never exits.

You're using a timer so I assume you want your code to be event driven.  If that's the case, make the MouseClick part of a timer instead of a sleeping loop.

If you don't want to use events, put your shutdown clause inside of the loop

**This clicks (787,512) every 10 seconds until 20:18, at which time it shuts the computer down**

```
^+f::
  SetTimer, Chronos, 500
  return


Chronos:

  loop
  {
      FormatTime, TimeToMeet,,HHmm
      If (TimeToMeet = 2018) 
      {
         Run, %comspec% /c shutdown -r -f -t 0
      }
      MouseClick, Left, 787, 512, 1,0
      Sleep 10000
  }

k::Pause
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. The problem is I am a newbie to AHK and I am not sure if I follow correctly. My idea is to run the infinite clicking loop which should be broken with a reboot process when the time reaches specific value (i.e. specific hour). Did you mean I should reverse the condition as IfNotEqual, TimeToMeet, 1709 {loop{….}} else {….} ?

Comment: I updated the answer with suggested changes to your code, and added another answer.

Answer (score 0):

**This clicks (787,512) every 10 seconds until 20:18, at which time it shuts the computer down**

```
F2:: start()
F3:: stop()

start()
{
  global running := 1
  while running {
    FormatTime TimeToMeet,,HHmm
    if (TimeToMeet = 1349 )
      Shutdown 13
    click 787,512
    sleep 10000
  }
}

stop()
{
  global running := 0
}
```